# How to mute Intellij IDEA after sbt project is imported

Tags: macos, scala, intellij-idea, sbt, osx-elcapitan

This is driving me insane. For some reason or the other, my editor talks after successfully importing an SBT project. It simply says:

> SBT project import

This embarrasses me at work and annoys me at home and I want to shut it up, forever if possible.

Any idea how to do this?

I am running a mac with El Capitan 10.11.6

Intellij Version

> IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.2
>   Build #IU-162.1628.40, built on August 16, 2016
>   JRE: 1.8.0_76-release-b216 x86_64
>   JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

To trigger

1. Add new dependency to `build.sbt`
2. Save file
3. Wait for sbt to import successfully

There is a possibility this is a mac issue and not intellij

Comment: I have this same problem, and there is nothing I could find in IntelliJ's bug tracker. It's very annoying but it's not clear how to resolve.

Comment: @Olayinka can u pls post a screen-shot?

Comment: @SupunWijerathne It talks I can only share an audio recording

Comment: You mean it actually talks right out load? That's bizarre ... I am wondering if you have configured you mac to speak out all system messages.

Comment: @marios Yes, it actually talks out loud and it is only Intellijj that does this

Answer (score 0):

Notification in IDEA are customizable:
[image]
"Read aloud" column is available on Mac only. By default it is disabled for all notification.

"SBT project import" notification currently goes with group name "scala". I'll make it more descriptive in future versions. If it is not there it is probably not initialized yet. Import some sbt project, listen to it for the last time and turn it off.

Comment: read aloud isn't selected for any of the options and it stills speaks